# Iterating over a collection (VBA)

Tags: vba, variables, excel, foreach

Hello I am new to VBA and I am trying to iterate over a collection i've made and execute an action for each value.

Here is my code:

```
Sub makeRowsMatch()

Dim rows As VBA.Collection
Set rows = New VBA.Collection

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim y As Integer


For i = 2 To 22203
For j = 2 To 121

If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(j, 38) Then
     rows.Add (i)

End If

Next j
Next i


For Each y As Object in rows
rows(y).Delete

Next y

End Sub
```

I keep on getting an error in the line:

```
For Each y As Object in rows
```

It keeps on getting highlighted yellow, but when I remove the above line is get the following error:

```
For Each control variable must be Variant or Object
```

Could someone explain why it is not letting me iterate over the values?
The whole issue of declaring variables is new to me.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can loop like that in VBA.  Rather than having "For Each y As Object in rows", at the top, "Dim y as Variant" and your loop can be "For Each y in rows"

Answer (score 7):

Declare `y` as `Variant`, i.e.:

```
Dim y As Variant
```

and change your loop like this:

```
For Each y In rows
```

Then the loop will work or, at least, it won't give you an error at *that* point.

But the next problem/error is inside the loop. This line:

```
rows(y).Delete
```

will give you an error "Object required", or something like that, because `rows(y)` return an Integer, so you can't call `Delete` on it. There's some confusion here because `rows` on its own means the `Rows` range of the active sheet. But you also named your collection as `rows`, so there's a naming conflict.

Rename your `rows` to, for example, `myrows` and it should then all work. However, I don't know what you're trying to do with the `Delete` line, so I can't advise further.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a conflict in your declarations and use. This line declares `y` as an `Integer`, clearly:

```
Dim y As Integer
```

But you then try to use it as an `Object`, either with

```
For Each y As Object in rows
```

or

```
For Each y in rows
```

Change the declaration to

```
Dim y As Object
```

(I'm not that familiar with VBA. If the above doesn't work, change the declaration to `Dim y As Variant` instead.)